# PATH issue for adding Android tools on Mac OS

Tags: android, bash, macos, mono

Could someone tell me what this error means.

I'm trying edit my path for my mac to consist of Android platform-tools as well as tools on mac.

I'm not allowed to run the android command to run the emulator from the terminal.

I'm new to using mac and this is beyond frustrating could you all share some links if so.

-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands: No such file or directory

Comment: Please explain how you tried to change the path. What did you do to cause the error?

Comment: I just type in $PATH and was giving this error message.   Before then I entered the following                                                                               export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/tools/
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/platform-tools/                                      Here's the link that I'm following: https://github.com/pjlantz/droidbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type `$PATH` on the command-line, it will try to execute the value as a command. This is not what you want. Instead, type a command that is contained in one of the directories on the patth, such as a command from Mono.

In order to add the Android tools to the path, you need to add the `<sdk-location>/tools` and `<sdk-location>/platform-tools` directories to your path. This will then allow you to run Android commands from the command-line. For the most part this is unnecessary since you can do everything from inside Android Studio anyway.

Comment: Okay you're right however the droidbox that I'm creating has to run from the terminal in order for me to run a droidbot.  I also figured it out and its running from the terminal. Just had to go within some files to execute the emulator.

Comment: @CassandraB Do you mean you had to go within some **directories** to execute the emulator? If you have set the PATH correctly, then this will not be necessary.

Comment: Yes. but I wasn't sure how to set the Path . My default path was returning a Path (directory or file ) was not found. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @CassandraB that is because you were trying to execute the path itself as a command. Instead you need to execute the emulator. If the path is set correctly it is used to find other commands.

Comment: correct. now I'm getting a kernel error for when I use the emulator -avd "Emulator name" @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @CassandraB Please post a new question with the exact error message. Be sure to explain exactly what you do that causes the error.